# How Does Shopware 6 Import/Export Module Work

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am working with the Shopware 6 Import/Export Module at `./vendor/shopware/core/Content/ImportExport`, I cannot find the code that stores the data in the product repository. However, I have seen the code that reads the CSV file. Where do you think I should look next, or is there something I am missing?